# Plotting vertical axis lines using values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have the following array in Jupyter, which I am using to plot as vertical lines from the x-axis.

```
array([6, 10, 18, 23, 29, 33, 50])
```

I am using `pylab` and `matplotlib` to do this.

I have produced the following code below thus far:

```py
mylist = array([6, 10, 18, 23, 29, 33, 50])
mylist
for i in mylist:
  axvline(mylist[i])
```

However, I get the following error and only my last value plotted:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-37afa3c95407> in <module>
      2 mylist
      3 for i in mylist:
----> 4     axvline(mylist[i])

IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7
```

I am struggling to understand what to do to rectify the problem.

What error am I making here?

[Photo showing graph being produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6GqD.png)

*I am unable to render my image in the question due to being a new user on this site.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the indexing wrongly. When you do `for i in mylist:`, you are directly looping over the elements. So you can't access the elements then using `mylist[i]` but you need to directly use `i`

> IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7

The error above occurs when you access the second element which is `10`. When `i=10`, you use it as `mylist[10]` which throws error because the length of `mylist` is 7 because it has 7 elements.

**Correct way:**

```
for i in mylist:
    plt.axvline(i)
```